# apt-get "Broken packages"

Tags: 12.04, apt, debian

While installing python-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

I am getting the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python2.7-dev : Depends: python2.7 (= 2.7.3-0ubuntu3) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
                Depends: libpython2.7 (= 2.7.3-0ubuntu3) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I already have python2.7 and libpython2.7 installed. I don't understand "0ubuntu3" and "0ubuntu3.1" means in the error.

I am on Ubuntu 12.04.
I've tried `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` several times. I've tried googling the problem, but can't find any solution to it. I don't want to `autoremove python`, its gonna remove 300MB of stuff, so I'm guessing more than one thing will stop working.

Since then I have reinstalled Ubuntu 12.04 and have pretty much installed nothing after that, no security updates etc. too. This time python-dev and libboost-dev installed without a hiccup. But am facing the same issue with `freeglut3-dev`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
freeglut3-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                      libgl-dev
                Depends: libglu1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                      libglu-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The feedback I've gotten till now suggests there should be related to the package manager. Has anyone faced this issue? Can someone help please?

Thanks

Comment: So apparently, this problem fixed itself when I opened the 'Update Manager' -> 'Settings' -> Check all for Update Sources (precise-security, -updates, -proposed, -backports). Close the Settings window. Then hit 'Check' in 'Update Manager' window. This somehow fixed the broken dependencies. And I was able to install everything smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

Please, try using the

```
apt-get -f install
```

command. It should install all missing dependencies.